# Arduino IDE libraries search

Tags: arduino-ide

Where I can do search libraries on WEB, that similar search in IDE? I did not find search page on `arduino.cc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The online analog of the Arduino IDE's Library Manager search feature is located here:

https://www.arduinolibraries.info/

That website is generated from the same index file Library Manager uses:

http://downloads.arduino.cc/libraries/library_index.json

Answer (score 3):

You get widest search with Google. Write "arduino" and then the device or topic name.

Most of the libraries have a [GitHub](https://github.com/) repository. You can use a search field on GitHub.

[A list of selected libraries](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/LibraryList) sorted by topic is on Arduino playground.

Comment: A good way to discover Arduino libraries on GitHub is the `arduino-library` topic: https://github.com/topics/arduino-library. It only contains repositories where the owner has bothered to add the topic but that's somewhat an indicator of how actively maintained the project is.

Answer (score 2):

You can search the [PlatformIO Library Database](https://platformio.org/lib). It covers libraries for many architectures and platforms, but if you add `framework:arduino` to the start of your search it narrows it down to just Arduino libraries.

From there you can go to the homepage or repository for a library you want.

It doesn't have all libraries, only the ones that have been set up for PlatformIO support, but that is quite a lot of libraries now.